# Minimal bash ubuntu's screen of death-in despair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bash

I am losing hope on my system and about to format...this is my last hope and I hope someone can help,attached are pics and boot repair file please help!

https://pastebin.com/DkaudicQ

I have a hp 15-ay039wm machine with 1TB HDD. I carved out two partitions about 30 gigs to install ubuntu 18LTS for dual boot. All was good until I stupidly made two changes which probably caused the issue, here they are:

1. I did a manufacturer upgrade from hp via hp assistant, this included some drivers and BIOS updates.
2. Using Aoemi partition software I split my main windows partition in two, but I didn't touch the ubuntu space at all.
   These are the two major things I can think of and now I get the grub minimal bash screen. I go exit, see win and ubuntu both as boot options when I chose windows it works, when I chose Ubuntu it takes me back to the minimal dash.
   I read endless articles about this and tried many things. I tried loading ubuntu from usb and installing boot repair and running that, it said everything was fixed but its still broken! I tried it again this time getting data for the more advanced users to look at.
   No matter what disk management software I use, they all say there is 32gigs unallocated space. None can detect my ubuntu installation at all yet its an option to boot at startup.

I tried  the initiate installing ubuntu as normal method, I read I would get an option to "reinstall ubunutu" this would keep my files but I wasn't presented with that option.

Right now my partitions are as follows:
 1. 460GB windows system and programs mainly
 2. 423 GB just pics,movies etc
 3. 13.6GB a win recovery system generated
 4. 2.43 GB small partition.

[screen of death](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNfai.jpg)
[ubuntu partitions showing as free space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRVFF.png)
[sda 7 is ubuntu related i think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGKhL.png)

Comment: Hello, you don't have /boot partition, maybe you can install, mark /dev/sda1 as /boot/efi I understand you using Ubuntu, but Arch Wiki have some good starting point and maybe can help you...

Comment: Can you read the Ubuntu partition, when running an Ubuntu live system ('Try Ubuntu' when booted from a USB pendrive or DVD disk)? In this case, I suggest that you backup everything that you cannot afford to lose (personal files etc) from that partition. - Then I think it might be easiest to reinstall Ubuntu, because it might be more difficult and time-consuming to identify and fix the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm using LVM, but this is my partition schema: http://ix.io/28My

Comment: @sistematico I am a linux newbie. do you think there is hope ? how do I do a linux boot partition, if you can link me to a resource with the steps I would be grateful.

sudodus I can boot from usb, try ubuntu yes, this is how I got the boot repair report: https://pastebin.com/DkaudicQ

Answer (score 0):

> I have a hp 15-ay039wm machine with 1TB HDD. I carved out two
>   partitions about 30 gigs to install ubuntu 18LTS for dual boot. All
>   was good until ...

I am very sorry, but the Bootinfo data, that you link to indicate that there is no linux partition in the internal drive, only partitions belonging to the Windows world (most of them with the NTFS file system).

The only thing that contains Ubuntu is the USB boot drive.

So it seems that at least one of those two actions (the hp upgrade and splitting partitions with the Aoemi partition software) caused the problem. Maybe splitting the partitions did something that you did not expect.

I hope that you have backed up everything that you cannot afford to lose. In that case you can start with Ubuntu from the beginning again - create some drive space for it and reinstall.

Otherwise you should avoid using the computer except for recovering data. The more you do, the more content from your Ubuntu partition might be overwritten.

Please let us know if you have a backup or not - it will help us decide how to continue.

Comment: Sadly I do not, I have many of the projects on an external drive but slightly older versions..better than nothing I guess. RIP :( 
Why does ubuntu show up as a boot option then so weird

Comment: There are some traces left in the EFI system partition. With the slightly older versions backed up on an external drive, I think it might not be worth the effort to try to recover a lot of files from the old Ubuntu partition. You could use [PhotoRec](https://cgsecurity.org) to recover a few files, if there is some particular file type that you have modified a lot since the backup.

Comment: Thank you...I think for the future I will keep an system image on an external drive at all time. Any suggestions for that? I dont want this to happen again

Comment: That's a good idea. I use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) for that purpose. A Clonezilla image is a directory with a set of files (most of them compressed). Clonezilla is smart enough to only copy used blocks (and skip free blocks), so it is much more efficient than crude cloning. There are also several checkpoints to help you avoid mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, I will learn how to use this software now and back everything up. Lesson learnt!

Comment: You are welcome and good luck, @distronub87 :-) It is best to download a Clonezilla iso file, create a USB boot drive and run Clonezilla from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help